# Incorrect syntax near word 'DECLARE'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

For some reason I keep getting the error 'Incorrect syntax near word 'DECLARE''. Where should I declare my variable so that it doesn't throw an error? I haven't been able to figure this out as I haven't found someone using a 'WITH AS' statement and also trying to declare a variable.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE qryKeysValues(@KeyValue varchar(5))
    AS
    BEGIN
    WITH tbl1 AS    
        (SELECT * FROM FN_qryMethods())

    DECLARE @SQL varchar(1500)
    SET @SQL = 'SELECT ' + @KeyValue+ ' AS fldCode, tbl' +@KeyValue+ 'Key.fldID, tbl1.fldID
               FROM tbl' + @KeyValue + 'Key', tbl1
        EXEC(@SQL)
    END;
```

Comment: *A CTE must be followed by a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, MERGE, or DELETE statement* - It's not clear what you are trying to do ...

Comment: You can declare your variable before `WITH` statement. I'd help you with an example, but it is very unclear what you are trying to achieve with your whole query. I don't see you using that `tbl1` anywhere and your dynamic sql seems messed (incorrect number of opening and closing apostrophes).

Comment: Sorry corrected those issues. I'm just trying to declare the @SQL string and then be able to execute it, the issue I'm running into is where to place the variable declaration (if it is possible at all).

Comment: What is the output of you `FN_qryMethods()`? And do you need that output inside dynamic SQL, or just to generate it? If you need it inside, you can't use WITH, you should switch to temp tables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `With` statement takes the structure:

```
WITH CTE_Name
AS
(
    Select column from table
)
Select column from CTE_Name
```

You can't put `Declare` where you are putting it.  Allowed values are `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `MERGE` (contrib @alex k).

Answer (score 4):

Maybe something like this is what you are looking for?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE qryKeysValues(@KeyValue varchar(5))
AS
BEGIN

  DECLARE @SQL varchar(1500);

  SELECT * INTO #tbl1 FROM FN_qryMethods();

  SET @SQL = 'SELECT ' + @KeyValue+ ' AS fldCode
                 , tbl' +@KeyValue+ 'Key.fldID
                 , #tbl1.fldID
              FROM tbl' + @KeyValue + 'Key, #tbl1';

  EXEC(@SQL);
END;
```

Comment: This works great, the only issue I'm having now is assigning a value to the @KeyValue variable when I call the procedure. When I try to do 'exec qryKeysValues('Ab')' it gives me an error of 'invalid column name'. I don't know why the variable refers to a column, what I need help with is passing a value to the procedure, if I passed qryKeyValues('Ab') for instance, I want the SQL string to say...          SELECT Ab AS fldCode, tblAbKey.fldID, #tbl1.fldID FROM tblAbKey, #tbl1;

Comment: @tripleddev It works exactly as you wrote in your last example. Selecting a column `ab` from table `tblAbKey`? Do you want just write `'ab'` string in `fldCode`?

Comment: @tripleddev If the answer is yes you should change part with setting varibale to `'SELECT ''' + @KeyValue+ ''' AS fldCode ...`

Comment: To clarify, I have multiple tables such as tblBbKey, tblAbKey, tblCcKey and so on. The variable is just to specify the two characters between 'tbl' and 'Key'. I could combine these tables and then query on WHERE clause, but it's not being allowed at the moment, so I'm doing all of this to work around it